# Laravel : Group users by month and output month name

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am querying users created in Laravel by month, here is my code

```
  $devlist = DB::table("users")
                ->select("id" ,DB::raw("(COUNT(*)) as month"))
                ->orderBy('created_at')
                ->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH(created_at)"))
                ->get();
```

This is giving me this

```
[{"id":1,"month":3},{"id":4,"month":4}]
```

How can I output the month as well instead of just the word month?  So my expected result would be

```
[{"id":1,"january":3},{"id":4,"febuary":4}]
```

Comment: Is the month label actually stored in the DB?

Comment: No, but the created_at field is a timestamp containing the month

Comment: The current result doesn't make sense - if its "groupBy" you would expect to have a nested result? It currently looks flat. I would expect to see something like `[{ "may": [{ "id":1, "month": 3 }, { "id":2, "month": 4 }] }]`

Comment: I have to say, your other question was answered well by people. Why did you re-ask the question? Also, I don't recommend setting it up this way, because then the data is not very usable. Maybe instead it should be: `[{"id":1,"month":"january"},{"id":4,"month":"febuary"}]`

Comment: My other question was answered perfect, however, this is a different question regarding outputting the name of the month

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's difficult to answer this without seeing the database, but I hope this will help:

```
$devlist = DB::table("users")
   ->select(DB::raw('EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at) AS month, COUNT(id) as id'))
   ->orderBy('created_at')
   ->groupBy(DB::raw('month'))
   ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$statement = Purchase::selectRaw('monthname(purchase_date) month')
            ->groupBy('month')
            ->orderByRaw('min(purchase_date) asc')
        ->get();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($statement);
        die;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing your DB structure, but something like this would be fine. As noted, the output you are showing doesn't line up with the groupBy clause, but assuming the groupBy is correct, this will restructure the way you need:

```
$devlist = DB::table("users")
                ->select("id" ,DB::raw("(COUNT(*)) as month"))
                ->orderBy('created_at')
                ->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH(created_at)"))
                ->get()
                ->map(function($monthItems, $month) {
                    return $monthItems->map(function($item) use ($month) {
                      return [
                          'id' => $item->id,
                          $month => $item->month,
                      ];
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this

```
\App\Model::selectRaw('monthname(date) as month, sum(total_amount) as total_sale')
        ->groupBy('month')
        ->orderByRaw('min(date) desc')
        ->get();
```